# Glossaries custom style overfull and underfull alignment

Tags: glossaries

I am reusing my custom glossaries style (based [on this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/161443/glossary-style-long-but-without-the-indentation-before-the-notations#161604) example) and I found out some issues lately.

I want to have a fixed spacing for both columns for a clean alignment.

This is the style I use:

```
\newglossarystyle{mystyle}{
  \setglossarystyle{long}
  \renewenvironment{theglossary}
  {\begin{longtable}{p{0.25\textwidth} p{0.7\textwidth}}}
  {\end{longtable}}
}
```

Here are two problems. As you can see, the total width of the `longtable` isn't 1, but 0.95 (otherwise the text will stick out, pretty weird)

The other problem I have is that I get overfull and underfull `\hbox` errors with these kind of glossaries:

```
\newglossaryentry{First}
{
    name={A glossary with a long name such as this one},
    description={And a small description}
}
\newglossaryentry{Second}
{
    name={Small name},
    description={And a long description, because this is just a test glossary. You know...}
}
```

The errors I get (don't mind the lines):

```
Underfull \hbox (badness 1303) in paragraph at lines 3--5 output.gls, line 3
Overfull \hbox (2.09003pt too wide) in alignment at lines 2--9 output.gls, line 2
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: Tabulars have also space between, before and after the columns. Use e.g. `\begin{longtable}{p{0.25\textwidth} p{\dimexpr0.75\textwidth-4\tabcolsep}}` to get a \textwidth wide tabular. For the other question you will have to make a small, complete example.

Comment: I fixed it by using `{p{0.25\textwidth} p{0.65\textwidth}}` Now it's also aligned with the list of figures and tables